# How to export mysql result(select data) in MFC

Tags: c++, mysql, mfc

I export .csv after executing select query using MFC

I use MFC via Visual C++ 6.0 and MySQL Server 5.X

```
MYSQL_RES m_res = mysql_store_result(&mysql);
```

I don't know how to use m_res connecting exporting .csv

Is it possible to export data?
If it is not, I will export data by .csv after displaying gridview.

Comment: MSVC 6.0 - seriously? That's 20 years of age now, totally outdated (and was well-known for very poor standard conformance even then). You should really switch to a [more modern version](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

Comment: Apart from, you should at provide a [mcve]. Have a look at [ask] as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, using MFC way (CString/CStringList, CArchive, etc.) :

```
    void PrintListCSV( CArchive &archiveContent, CStringList & strList, CString szSeparator ){

            if( strList.IsEmpty() )
                    return;

            CString strOneRecord;

            POSITION posTail = GetTailPosition();
            POSITION pos;

            for( pos = strList.GetHeadPosition(); pos != posTail; )
            {
                    CString str = strList.GetNext( pos );
                    strOneRecord += str;
                    strOneRecord += szSeparator;
            }

            strOneRecord += strList.GetNext( postTail );
            strOneRecord += _T("\r\n"); // windows change a line
            archiveContent.WriteString(strOneRecord);
    }


    BOOL ExportCSV( CString strFileName, MYSQL_RES * mysql_res )
    {
            CFile filePersistent;
            if( !filePersistent.Open( strFileName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite))
            {
                    //Error log, message box, etc.
                    return FALSE;
            }

            CArchive archiveContent( &filePersistent, CArchive::store);
            CString strSeparator(_T(";"));

            MYSQL_FIELD *field;

            //print column name - optional 
            CStringList fieldList;
            unsigned int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(mysql_res);

            while((field = mysql_fetch_field(mysql_res)) != NULL )
            {
                    fieldList.AddTail( field->name );
            }

            PrintListCSV( archiveContent, fieldList, strSeparator );

            //print each record set
            while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_res)))
            {
                    CStringList recordList;
                    for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
                    {
                            recordList.AddTail( row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL" );
                    }

                    PrintListCSV( archiveContent, recordList, strSeparator );
            }

            archiveContent.Close();
            filePersistent.Close();

            return TRUE;
    }
```

**How to use:**

```
    //some where in your main function ...
    //Open mysql connection, execute SQL commande ...
    // ...

    MYSQL_RES *m_res = mysql_store_result(&mysql);
    CString szFileName("C:\\SOME_PATH\\FILENAME.csv");

    if( !ExportCSV( szFileName, m_res ) ){
            //Cannot export to CSV file ...
            //Error message, log, etc.
    }

    //free the SQL result
    mysql_free_result( m_res );

    //...
```

**Warning:** This code can contain compiler errors. Hope that my memory serves me right.

Comment: thank you for your comment i try that and if i don't know that, i will ask later thank you!